# How to fill an pie shape area in WPF XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have the following XAML:

```
    <Ellipse StrokeThickness="2" Stroke="Green"></Ellipse>
    <Rectangle Margin="150,0,149,150" Name="rectanglePie" Stroke="Green" Height="150" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
        <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
            <RotateTransform x:Name="pieEdge" CenterX="0" CenterY="150" Angle="60" />
        </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
    </Rectangle>

    <Rectangle Margin="150,0,149,150" Name="rectangleStatic" Stroke="Green" Height="150" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
    </Rectangle>
```

What I would like to do is to fill the pie slice that this contains with a colour.  Is this possible, and if so, how would I go about this?

Comment: The pie slice that contains *what*?  And what is the container holding these shapes?

Comment: That's an odd looking pie amigo, why not just grab the wpf toolkit and use a chart control? However if you're just calling your `Rectangle` a "slice" then just a Fill="Color" will suffice.

Comment: Not sure how exactly that pie shape looks. Isn't that the Ellipse is enough? Or you want some kind of Arc (not a full ellipse)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get you started...

```
<Canvas>
    <Path Canvas.Left="150"
          Canvas.Top="150"
          Fill="Blue"
          Stroke="Black">
        <Path.Data>
            <PathGeometry>
                <PathFigure StartPoint="0 0"
                            IsClosed="True">
                    <LineSegment Point="200 110" />
                    <LineSegment Point="-100,100"/>
                    <ArcSegment x:Name="arc"
                                Size="100 100"
                                SweepDirection="ClockWise" />
                </PathFigure>
            </PathGeometry>
        </Path.Data>
    </Path>
</Canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks, this put me on the right path.  I ended up finding this blog post, which is almost exactly what I wanted: http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2012/06/windows-8-animated-pie-slice.html